# Pig and Jython - Can't Register UDF

Tags: apache-pig, jython, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am trying to write it Python UDF; I am using the Datastax package for that.  When I try to write a simple UDF such as:

```
@outputSchema("word:chararray")
def helloworld():  
    return 'Hello, World'
```

And then register it in the grunt shell:

```
REGISTER 'pig.py' USING org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine as myfuncs;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/python/core/PyObject
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/core/PyObject
>           at org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine.registerFunctions(JythonScriptEngine.java:304)
>           at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerCode(PigServer.java:534)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processRegister(GruntParser.java:423)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:419)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:190)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:166)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
>           at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:490)
>           at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.python.core.PyObject not found in modules [ModuleClassLoader:Ana$
>           at com.datastax.bdp.loader.SystemClassLoader.loadClass(SystemClassLoader.java:120)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:38)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:32)
>
> ## ... 14 more

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: Hi Bruno, did you try the suggestion below?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but now i get the error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/compiler/Code
        at org.python.compiler.ClassFile.addMethod(ClassFile.java:76)

Answer (score 0):

Add $PIG_HOME/lib/jython.jar to your PIG_CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Now the error is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/compiler/Code
        at org.python.compiler.ClassFile.addMethod(ClassFile.java:76) Do you know what can be?